# How can I install a subfolder of a github repository using yarn?

Tags: github, npm, dependencies, yarnpkg

I'm trying to add a library as a dependency to a project.

This library is setup in a fairly peculiar way, with this file structure

```
package.json
library/
    package.json
```

in `/package.json` the `name` is just `parent-folder`, while in `/library/package.json` the name is `library-name`.

On npm it's also published as `library-name`.

What I'm trying to do is creating my own fork and installing this library using yarn without release a npm package.

Is this possible? How can you achieve this?

Comment: It seems that they added it to yarn 2
https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/issues/4725